# Terminar while loop con break, pero sigue en bucle infinito

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy iniciándome en Python y en la programación en general y ahora que ya tenía unos cuantos apuntes en mano, me he lanzado a escribir un simple programa que consta de un menú con diferentes opciones.

La primera consta simplemente de un bucle que permite introducir edades en una lista.

El problema que tengo es que después de pedir confirmación en el bucle para salir el `break` no hace que la condición sea `false` y termine el loop. He probado con un `return False` y el resultado es el mismo, no me termina el loop para invocar la función `menu()` y volver al inicio.

```
while True:                             # bucle para introducir edades en la lista
    valor = input("Introduce edad: ")   # pedir valor por teclado
    listaedad.append(valor)             # añadir valor a listaedad
    confirm = input('Quieres seguir? ') # confirmación para seguir con el bucle

    if confirm in ('s', 'si', 'Si', 'SI'):      # si confirm es igual a los valores del IN
        continue                                # continua en el while
    elif confirm in ('n', 'no', 'No', 'NO'):    # si confirm es igual a los valores de IN
        print("Saliendo...")                    # imprime mensaje de salida
        break                                   # sal del bucle
    else:                                       # si confirm es cualquier otro valor distinto de SI/NO
        print('Opción no reconocida')           # imprime mensaje
        print('Saliendo...')                    # imprime mensaje
        break                                   # sal del bucle
return listaedad                        #retorna la lista
menu()              # vuelve al menu de inicio
```

Comment: Podrias ver si te sirve quit() en vez de break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `return listaedad`

No es necesario que devuelvas el valor de lista edad. "Return" se utiliza para que una función retorne un valor. Si la variable listaedad está declarada más arriba como global puedes ver su contenido cuando quieras. Para que lo veas mejor te voy a poner el código como ejemplo:

```
import os


listaedad = list ();

def limpiarPantalla():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def menu ():
    print ('''
    Elige una opción:

        1. Añadir edad a la lista
        2. Ver lista de edades
        3. Salir del programa

        ''')

    opcion = input ('')
    return opcion



while True:
    limpiarPantalla ()
    opcion_elegida = menu ();
    limpiarPantalla ()
    if opcion_elegida == "1":

        while True:                             # bucle para introducir edades en la lista
            valor = input("Introduce edad: ")   # pedir valor por teclado
            listaedad.append(valor)             # añadir valor a listaedad
            confirm = input('Quieres seguir? ') # confirmación para seguir con el bucle

            if confirm in ('s', 'si', 'Si', 'SI'):      # si confirm es igual a los valores del IN
                pass                           # continua en el while
            elif confirm in ('n', 'no', 'No', 'NO'):    # si confirm es igual a los valores de IN
                print("Saliendo...")                    # imprime mensaje de salida
                break                                  # sal del bucle
            else:                                       # si confirm es cualquier otro valor distinto de SI/NO
                print('Opción no reconocida')           # imprime mensaje
                print('Saliendo...')                    # imprime mensaje
                break                                   # sal del bucle

    elif opcion_elegida == "2":

        for i in listaedad:
            print (i)
        print ("Pulsa cualquier tecla para volver al menu")
        input ('')


    elif opcion_elegida == "3":
        break

    else:
        print ("Opción no disponible")
```

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, parece ser que el problema estaba en el return (sigo sin entender por qué se me habrá ocurrido ponerlo ahí) pero el caso es que después de eliminarlo el bucle ya termina correctamente después del break. La variable listaedad la declaro dentro de la función pero como según comentas mejor declararla fuera como global así en el resto de funciones tendré mejor acceso a su contenido. Gracias por tu ejemplo de código, ahora a seguir con el resto de funciones y a tratar de entender mejor como funciona el return para entender el fallo. Saludos! :)

Answer (score 1):

`return` se usa dentro de funciones o métodos. ¿Este bucle `while` forma parte de una función? Si es así, por favor, añade el código completo.

Si el `while` no está dentro de una función o método si eliminas el `return` debería funcionar correctamente.

Si el bucle `while` forma parte de la función puedes poner el `return` en lugar de los `break`s para que devuelva `listaedad` justo en el momento en que el `while` deja de cumplirse.

Comment: Buenas, ante todo gracias por tu comentario, comentar que sí que el while está dentro de una función. Parece ser que eliminando el return listaedad como según comentaba el compañero @raul funciona, ahora el bucle termina de manera correcta. Gracias por tu ayuda y saludos.